# Array has multi strings against text with multiline ( regular expression) Python

Tags: python, regex

I am working on the regular expression on python. I spend the whole week I can't understand what wrong with my code. it obvious that multi-string should match, but I get a few of them. such as "model" , '"US"" but I can't match 37abc5afce16xxx and "-104.99875". My goal is just to tell whether there is a match for any string on the array or not and what is that matching.

I have string such as:'

```
       text =  {'"version_name"': '"8.5.2"', '"abi"': '"arm64-v8a"', '"x_dpi"': 
         '515.1539916992188', '"environment"': '{"sdk_version"', 
        '"time_zone"': 
       '"America\\/Wash"', '"user"': '{}}', '"density_default"': '560}}', 
       '"resolution_width"': '1440', '"package_name"': 
       '"com.okcupid.okcupid"', '"d44bcbfb-873454-4917-9e02-2066d6605d9f"': '{"language"', '"country"': 
       '"US"}', '"now"': '1.515384841291E9', '{"extras"': '{"sessions"', 
      '"device"': '{"android_version"', '"y_dpi"': '37abc5afce16xxx', 
      '"model"': '"Nexus 6P"', '"new"': 'true}]', '"only_respond_with"': 
      '["triggers"]}\n0\r\n\r\n', '"start_time"': '1.51538484115E9', 
     '"version_code"': '1057', '"-104.99875"': '"0"', '"no_acks"': 'true}', 
     '"display"': '{"resolution_height"'}
```

An array has multi-string as :

```
Keywords =["37abc5afce16xxx","867686022684243", "ffffffff-f336-7a7a-0f06-65f40033c587", "long", "Lat", "uuid", "WIFI", "advertiser", "d44bcbfb-873454-4917-9e02-2066d6605d9f","deviceFinger", "medialink", "Huawei","Andriod","US","local_ip","Nexus", "android2.10.3","WIFI", "operator", "carrier", "angler", "MMB29M", "-104.99875"]
```

My code as

```
for x in Keywords:

    pattern = r"^.*"+str(x)+"^.*"
    if re.findall(pattern, str(values1),re.M):
        print "Match"
        print x
    else:
        print "Not Match"
```

Comment: I am dealing with multi-type of encodes. it is a network traffic

Comment: I think the problem could be caused by the second `^` in the expression `r"^.*"+str(x)+"^.*"`. The `^` (carret) matches the beginning of a line (see [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax))

Comment: I deleted but it is not work

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), at least some expected values. Otherwise, we can just produce guesswork.

Comment: You should switch to Python 3.6 while you are still learning - https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 1):

Your code's goal is a bit confusing, so this is assuming you want to check for which items from the `Keywords` list are also in the `text` dictionary

In your code, it looks like you only compare the regex to the dictionary values, not the keys (assuming that's what the `values1` variable is).

Also, instead of using the regex "^.*" to match for strings, you can simply do

```
for X in Keywords:
    if X in yourDictionary.keys():
        doSomething
    if X in yourDictionary.values():
        doSomethingElse
```

Comment: I am not dealing with Dictionary all the time. I may have many formats Json , Pairs and even unknow formal

Comment: Write the code for lists, then convert the any dictionaries that come by.